# Problem in output when nCr fuction is created using factorial function

Tags: c++, recursion, pascals-triangle

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return fact(n - 1) * n;
    }
}

int ncr(int n, int r)
{
    int a = fact(n);
    int b = fact(n - r) * fact(r);

    return a / b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "ncr(6,3) is : " << ncr(6, 3) << endl;
    cout << "ncr(13,4) is : " << ncr(13, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
ncr(6,3) is : 20
ncr(13,4) is : 221
```

The output till `n=12` is correct, but after that when `n > 12` the output is mathematically incorrect.

What is the problem? There is no error shown in VS Code.

Comment: Signed integer overflow, leading to undefined behavior? Remember that on almost every system you might come in contact with, `int` is a signed 32-bit integer type, with values from about minus two billion, to plus two billion. If you go beyond that you get the above mentioned undefined behavior. You can extend it a little by using unsigned integers instead, and a lot by using `unsigned long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. But even that have a limit.

Comment: *so what is the problem* -- You need to put in more effort to find the issue.  At the very least, print out the values of `a` and `b` in your `ncr` function.  Are they what you expect?

Comment: Note that `13!` is `6227020800` (~6e9), while `2^32` is only `4294967296` (~4e9). You'd need at least 33 bits to represent `13!` as an unsigned integer.

Comment: As the other comments already recommend, use an unsigned integer type with more bytes so that you can store bigger values. In addition you could take some time and think of the mathematical expression. `n!/(k!(n-k)!)`. What about the parts that cancel each other out in the division? On one hand calculating those could lead to larger numbers and therefore overflow, on the other hand they are wasted computations. So there is room for some optimizations, especially with larger numbers and `k` close to `n`.

Comment: One way to compute a binomial coefficient in a way that doesn't overflow that quickly goes like this: `n / 1 * (n-1) / 2 * (n-2) / 3 * ... * (n-r+1) / r` . Proving correctness and Implementing this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What is the maximum value you need to support for the inputs?

Comment: Surprisingly, the fastest way to compute nCr may well turn out to be using Pascal’s triangle. It’s also easier to identify the point of overflow.